# Python pandas to filter the data based on date range in ascending order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm loading csv file and  It has three columns: a column with date and time, a column with a value, and another 'data'. Example rows:

```
 value data                 Date-Time
0      2    a     2019-3-18 23:11:00
1      3    b     2019-10-24 21:00:12
2      1    c     2019-1-10 23:00:00
3      2    d     2019-4-18 23:11:00
4      1    e     2019-1-1 23:00:00
```

I want group by value if we get duplicates on value need to fetch record based on recent record of date and time  it should look as follows.

```
  value data                date
0      1    c 2019-1-10 23:00:00
1      2    d 2019-04-18 23:11:00
2      3    b 2019-10-24 21:00:12


df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df = df.sort_values("date").groupby(['value'], as_index=False).first()

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`:

```
# Convert 'Date-Time' column to datetime64
# df['Date-Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date-Time'])

>>> df.sort_values('Date-Time') \
      .drop_duplicates('value', keep='last') \
      .sort_values('value')

   value data           Date-Time
2      1    c 2019-01-10 23:00:00
3      2    d 2019-04-18 23:11:00
1      3    b 2019-10-24 21:00:12
```